# Changing ActionBar Text and Button color when using Theme.AppCompat.Light

Tags: android, android-actionbar

This is my `styles.xml` file and the theme I am using `AppTheme2`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FF5722</item>
    <!--<item name="android:statusBarColor">#E64A19</item>-->

    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#E64A19</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>

    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
         which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF9800</item>

    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>



    <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
         colorControlHighlight & colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->

</style>
```

I prefer to use `Theme.AppCompat.Light` because this changed the color of my navigation drawer to white as desired but unfortunately changed the color of the buttons and text in the action bar to black and I just want them to be white. How can I accomplish this?

(The `android:textColor` field has no effect, and removing "android" from it causes an xml error when compiling)

Answer (score 1):

You must use below theme for achieving title text color and back button color to white.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

This theme would by default change it.

Answer (score 0):

`textColorPrimary` effects the action bar text:

```
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#fff</item>
```

Alternatively, inheriting from `DarkActionBar` Theme will use white text in the action bar:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Answer (score 0):

The theme `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` was exactly what I needed to use. Solved my problem!